# Parenthesis after variable name C++

Tags: c++, syntax

Working with the below source code (it is open source) and I've never seen parenthesis after a variable name. UDefEnergyH is definitely a variable as can be seen in line 1. Can anyone tell me what these parenthesis are doing? Don't really know how to Google this. Thanks.

```
bins[0] = UDefEnergyH.GetLowEdgeEnergy(size_t(0));
vals[0] = UDefEnergyH(size_t(0)); //Don't know what this does???
sum = vals[0];
for (ii = 1; ii < maxbin; ii++) {
    bins[ii] = UDefEnergyH.GetLowEdgeEnergy(size_t(ii));
    vals[ii] = UDefEnergyH(size_t(ii)) + vals[ii - 1];
    sum = sum + UDefEnergyH(size_t(ii));
}
```

And it is declared here in the header file:

```
G4PhysicsOrderedFreeVector UDefEnergyH;
```

Comment: Operator overloading

Comment: Actually without additional context we may not be able to answer this question. What @MohitJain proposes is definitely one possible explanation

Comment: `UDefEnergyH` is an instance of an object. `UDefEnergyH(0)` calls its overloaded function call operator `UDefEnergyH::operator()(std::size_t i)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears `operator()` is overloaded for the tyupe of `UDefEnerfyH`.

One way to do this is [this solution](http://ideone.com/qyoOmD)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct MJ {
    void GetLowEdgeEnergy(size_t arg) {
        cout << "GetLowEdgeEnergy, arg = " << arg << endl;
    }
    void operator ()(size_t arg) {
        cout << "operator (), arg = " << arg << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    MJ UDefEnergyH;
    UDefEnergyH.GetLowEdgeEnergy(42);
    UDefEnergyH(42);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, completely forgot that was a thing. Thanks, that was it. I'l mark it as a best answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: Isn't it also possible that it's actually a function pointer? =)

Comment: @Mints97 No because of `UDefEnergyH.GetLowEdgeEnergy` line in the code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are referring to the field in the class [G4SPSEneDistribution](http://hepg.sdu.edu.cn/zhangxueyao/software_doc/Geant4/html/classG4SPSEneDistribution.html). Its type is [G4PhysicsOrderedFreeVector](http://hepg.sdu.edu.cn/zhangxueyao/software_doc/Geant4/html/classG4PhysicsOrderedFreeVector.html).  And have a look at its [members here](http://hepg.sdu.edu.cn/zhangxueyao/software_doc/Geant4/html/classG4PhysicsOrderedFreeVector-members.html). As you can see there is [operator() overloaded](http://hepg.sdu.edu.cn/zhangxueyao/software_doc/Geant4/html/classG4PhysicsVector.html#a8) and apparently this is what is called on the second line. It is not very easy to find out what that does, but if you have a look at the comment in the header file [for G4PhysicsVector](http://hepg.sdu.edu.cn/zhangxueyao/software_doc/Geant4/html/G4PhysicsVector_8hh-source.html), you will see:

```
00100          // Returns simply the value in the bin specified by 'binNumber'
00101          // of the dataVector. The boundary check will not be Done. If 
00102          // you want this check, use the operator [].
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is known as direct initialization, in which it first constructs the object with '0' as an immediate parameter, and then assigns it to the first index of the vals array.

Comment: You meant the vals array